# PHP Database class, or the code using the class is not working

Tags: php, mysql, oop, xampp

Hello I've made Php class for my database, i'm using XAMPP on windows 10.

It seems something is wrong and I can't find the problem, I don't know if it's in my class file or in my inex.php file

This is the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'db' not found in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\userInfo.php:5 Stack trace: #0 D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\userInfo.php(43): showData() #1 {main} thrown in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\userInfo.php on line 5

db.php

```
<? php
class db{
  private $_conn;
  private $_host = "localhost";
  private $_username = "root";
  private $_psw = "";
  private $_dbName = "users";

  public function __construct(){
    $this->_conn = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_psw, $this->_dbName);

    if ($this->_conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $this->_conn->connect_error);
    }
  }

  public function getCon(){
    return $this->_conn;
  }
}
?>
```

userInfo.php

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/db.php';

function showData(){
  $conn = new db();
  $br = 1; //br is used to displat the number of each row in the table.

  $userQuery = "SELECT* FROM users";
  $result = $conn->getCon()->query($userQuery);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr> <td>" .$br ."</td> <td>" .$row["first_name"] ."</td> <td>" .$row["last_name"] ."</td> <td>" .$row["nickname"] ."</td> <td>" .$row["user_id"] ."</td> <br>" ;
      $br ++;
    }
  }
  $conn->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Users Info</title>
    <!-- adding JS scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- adding css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- my CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Nickname</th>
          <th>User ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php showData(); ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no idea, how to fix it. I tried 

`$database = new db();
   $conn = $database->getCon();
`
stil not working

Comment: It may be because your `__construct` function is private in `db.php`

Comment: along with other advice here you have a typo when instantiating your mysqli class. You have msqli and should be mysqli, you are missing the "y".

Comment: Thank it helped a lot, but now it's saying that the db.php class is not included, but it's included.

I have updated the post can you check the new error and code?

Comment: Is there a way to bump a post ?

Answer (score -1):

Your $conn variable is not the connection but a wrapper, rather your connection is in:  $conn->getCon()

So you can use:

```
$result = $conn->getCon()->query($userQuery);
```

Comment: In addition: your construction should be public thanks @haslam

Comment: I just tried it sir, still not working.

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php on line 21


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCon() on null in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php on line 21

Comment: formProcess.php  line 21 referers to $conn whereas it has not been instantiated in that context. Write $conn = new db(); there as well

Comment: Thank you sir. I found a closing bracket of my function on the wrong place I removed it and it worked, but now I have new error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'db' not found in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php:10 Stack trace: #0 D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php(57): showData() #1 {main} thrown in D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php on line 10

It also is displaying the tables header rows, I guess it gives the error when the script calls the showData function in the table.

Comment: add require_once 'classes/db.php';
 in your formProcess script

Comment: It is added sir. Actually my formProcess.php is code that I show in the post, I just sayed that it's called index.php.

I will update the index.php code in the post and will put the new error message.